# List all blog categories

Tags: blog, categories

I have created a blog plugin. I have the blog category in my blog. I would like to get the list of all the blog categories and list it in my www.domain.com/blogs/ page. My blog category name is 'blogcategory' . I do not know how to use it in the `list-category` function.

I am a nooby to wordpress development.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can I use the following code for my question.

```
<?php $args = array('taxonomy' => 'blogcategory'); ?>
<?php $tax_menu_items = get_categories( $args );
foreach ( $tax_menu_items as $tax_menu_item ):?>

    <a href="<?php echo get_term_link($tax_menu_item,$tax_menu_item->taxonomy); ?>">
        <?php echo $tax_menu_item->name; ?>
    </a>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

I found it from [here](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/getting-custom-taxonomy-link)

**Updated: I found the answer I was looking for**

```
<?php

$taxonomy = 'blogcategory';
$tax_terms = get_terms($taxonomy);
?>
<ul>
<?php
foreach ($tax_terms as $tax_term) {
echo '<li>' . '<a href="' . esc_attr(get_term_link($tax_term, $taxonomy)) . '" title="' . sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $tax_term->name ) . '" ' . '>' . $tax_term->name.'</a></li>';
}
?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

As of 2023, you can use the [List Categories plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/list-categories/) with its own configurable shortcode, which behaves exactly as a direct shortcut to the `wp_list_categories( array|string $args = '' )` [function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_list_categories/).

You can configure its arguments as documente there as well.